# Placeholder in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, placeholder

HI Currently I am using this placeholder text on my search Name or Area of Expertise but I have to change this text to this: **Consultant's name -OR- Area of expertise**

```
<?php   e($form->input('City.keyword',array('id'=>'CityKeyword','div'=>false,'label'=>false,'class'=>'forminput-new','placeholder'=>'Name or Area of expertise','value'=>$keyword,'style'=>'width:99%;')))  ?>
```

I am facing difficulty what should I use to decode ' & - this sign in text

Comment: Sorry I have solved my problem by doing in this way

    <?php   e($form->input('City.keyword',array('id'=>'CityKeyword','div'=>false,'label'=>false,'class'=>'forminput-new',"placeholder"=>"Consultant's name -OR- Area of expertise",'value'=>$keyword,'style'=>'width:99%;')))  ?>

thanks

Comment: set it as a answer not comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, I have solved my problem by doing this:

```
<?php   e($form->input('City.keyword',array(
    'id'=>'CityKeyword',
    'div'=>false,
    'label'=>false,
    'class'=>'forminput-new',
    "placeholder"=>"Consultant's name -OR- Area of expertise",
    'value'=>$keyword,
    'style'=>'width:99%;'
)))  ?>
```

Thanks.